# Neo4j gem - Plucking multiple nodes/relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, neo4j.rb, pluck

This may not be possible as it is right now but I have a query like so

`events = Event.as(:e).where("(( e.date_start - {current_time} )/{one_day_p}) < 1 ").users(:u, :rel).where("rel.reminded = {reminded_p}" ).params(reminded_p: false, one_day_p: one_day, current_time: time).pluck(:e,:u, :rel)`

The goal is to obtain the `events` where the start_date is less than a day away. Hypothetically I've tried to pluck the event, the user and the relationship. I need to do a different action with each.

I need to get all the `users` for each `event` and perform an email action for each user. In that action, the email needs to have access to that `event`.

Next, I need to update the `rel.reminded` property to `true`.

Is there a way to pluck all these simultaneously to be able to organize and perform these tasks? I started doing this individually but I have to make extra queries to make it happen. e.g.

`events = Event.as(:e).where("(( e.date_start - {current_time} )/{one_day_p}) < 1 ").users(:u, :rel).where("rel.reminded = {reminded_p}" ).params(reminded_p: false, one_day_p: one_day, current_time: time).pluck(:e)`

then I have to

```
events.each do |event|
# do stuff
end

# do another query that is associated and do more stuff
```

Update:

Incorporating the answers, I have something like this without the cleaned up time method yet. I added in a where search for user as I will need to factor that in later in the email function. So I am not sure if it's more efficient to include it in the query vs doing it outside per user.

```
@collection = Event.as(:e).where("(( e.date_start - {current_time} )/{one_day_p}) < 1 ").users(:u).where(setting_reminder: true).rel_where(reminded: false ).params(one_day_p: one_day, current_time: time).pluck(:e, 'COLLECT(u)', 'COLLECT(rel)')
```

but `rel` is not defined with this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you're using v4 of the gem, use `rel_where` instead of `where` with a string for your relationship!

You should be able to change your pluck to `pluck(:e, 'COLLECT(u)', 'COLLECT(rel)')` and it'll give you a big enumerable of events, users, and rels, all grouped in parent arrays based on event. It'd be organized like this:

```
  [
    [event1, [user1a, user1b, user1c], [rel1a, rel1b, rel1c]],
    [event2, [user2a, user2b, user2c], [rel2a, rel2b, rel2c]]
  ]
```

The position of each rel matches its user, so `rel1a` is the relationship between the event and `user1a`.

You can set that to `@collection = my_big_query` and then do `@collection.each do |event, users, rels|` in your view to loop through. You'd do `each_with_index` on users and the index of the user would correspond to the position within `rels`. It'd look something like:

```
<%= @collection.each do |event, users, rels| %>
  <%= event.name %>
  <% users.each_with_index do |user, i| %>
    <%= user.name %> said they were attending at <%= rels[i].confirmed_at %>.<br />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Finally returned to this. with the collect method like so  `@collection = Event.as(:e).where("(( e.date_start - {current_time} )/{one_day_p}) < 1 ").users(:u).rel_where(reminded: false ).params(one_day_p: one_day, current_time: time).pluck(:e, 'COLLECT(u)', 'COLLECT(rel)')` It doesn't know what `rel` is in the collect. It says `rel not defined`. I added an edit to what I want to change it to

Comment: You should probably do `)/{one_day_p}) < {one}` and add `one: 1` to your params, too. :-/

Comment: Posted a follow up question to avoid making this too long

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted to chime in on a couple of points.  You should be able to use ActiveSupport to make part of the query easier like this:

```
Event.as(:e).where("date_start < {date_threshold}").params(1.day.from_now)
```

Also, to make it less cluttered I don't see any problem in putting `.where("rel.reminded = false")` (or using `rel_where(reminded: false)` as Chris suggested).  This isn't data passed in from the user and it doesn't change at different times when you call the query, so it should be just as efficient.

You also may want to use the new query chaining in the v4 of the gem to define a `unreminded_users` method like this:

```
class Event
  def self.unreminded_users
    all.rel_where(reminded: false)
  end
end
```

I've actually not tried doing a `rel_where` like that in a query chain, but I suspect it will work.  Then you'll just have this:

```
Event.as(:e).where("e.start_date < {date_threshold}").params(date_threshold: 1.day.from_now)
  .users(:u, :rel).rel_where(reminded: false)
  .pluck(:e,:u, :rel)
```

Comment: To be clear, I still very much support the `collect` approach mentioned by Chris and we hope to implement eager loading so that you can do this via object method calls in the near future

Comment: I finally got around to returning to this task. I didn't really get where the new query chaining method you added fits in but I'll try to check out the docs to learn more about it

Comment: It's pretty new (I think it went into the latest patch version of 3.0.x, but it probably should have waited until a minor or major version).  Basically it just lets you reuse parts of a query chain in various queries.  Check out this blog post about ActiveRecord which is very similar: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/

Comment: On a slight tangent to the q, but I believe neither methods work for detecting the threshold. In my case, it will detect past events too. And if the user changes their settings to receive updates in the future, it will fire off those past events. I think in your answer, `e.start_date` is always `< date_threshold` until start_date passes that `1.day.from_now` since that is in the future.